# Textbox Contains Only Certain Characters C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a simple WinForms app that generates random numbers based on the maximum number entered. For the maximum number text box I already have code that checks the 'key press' input so that numbers and "." are the only characters input. Hence, decimal numbers are allowed. However, I also want to check that the text box doesn't just contain 0's and "." An outline of my code is shown below:

```
            if(txbInput.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            validation fails
        }

        else if(txbInput Contains just 0s and .)
        {
            validation also fails
        }

        else{
            do maths
        }
```

What would be the correct way to do this in the 'else if' statement?

Comment: yes it would be however you are best doing Regex (Regular Expressions) for pattern matching. For example, how do you know how many 0's there would be? Doing a .Contains("0") is not good and will blow out even if you have 1 zero or x zero's. Regex is pattern matching allowing you to do a strict pattern search which is more reliable than doing string checks using Contains etc...

Comment: @Ahmedilyas he doesn't use Contains, his expression is just by pseudo code, not actual code, and the important thing is he uses **Contains just** not just **Contains**.

Comment: @KingKing thanks. Mine was also an example of using the string methods, contains, indexof etc... etc... :)

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you use `Decimal.TryParse` or `Double.TryParse` instead?

```
decimal d;
if(!decimal.TryParse(txbInput.Text, out d))
{
    // validation fails, output an appropriate message to the user
}
else if (d == 0m)
{
    // validation fails, output an appropriate message to the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a [NumericUpDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/729xt55s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control instead of TextBox. This will eliminate validation and parsing in your code, except for comparing its *Value* property with zero.
**Remark**: To use this control for editing a real numbers, set an appropriate values for the properties *DecimalPlaces* and *Increment*.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the KeyPressEvent for that...
like

```
 private void tb1_KeyPressed(object o,KeyPressEvents e)
 {
     if(/*insert your validation here*/)
     {//valid case
       e.Handled=false;
     }
     else
     {//false case
       e.Handled=true;
       //inform user about mistake
     }
 }
```

if you set Handled =true then nothing will happen after a key got pressed. Through that you can surpress keys in a textbox